# Why do my props not work in grandchild component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Tried to transfer data from 2 components to one using the same method, but it is working only for 50%. There are 3 documents: App.js, Hort.js, Hord.js. Transfering from app.js to hort.js is working, but from hord.js to hort.js isn't. What could be the reason?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Hort from './Hort'

function App(props) {
    const text1 = 'check1'
    return (
        <Hort test1={text1} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hord.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Hort from './Hort'

function Hord(props) {
    const text2 = 'check2'
    return (
        <Hort test2={text2} />
    );
}

export default Hord;
```

Hort.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'
import Hord from './Hord'

function Hort(props) {
    
    return (
       <div>
            <h1>Just {props.test1}</h1>
            <h2>Just {props.test2}</h2>
        </div>
        )
}

export default Hort;
```

Comment: Where you are calling Hord component?

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? The values you pass as props aren't rendering properly? Also where is `Hord` rendered (I'm assuming `App` is the usual base component)? Also did you intend to import `Hort` and `App` into `Hort`? (this will give you an import cycle)

Comment: @Maaas did you try out my answer? Consider giving some feedback

Comment: @axtck thx for ur help. U were right. Everything we want it to work needs to be rendered in the main document. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never rendering `<Hord>`, if a component is never rendered, it won't render what's inside it.

In your *index.js*, you probably have code that looks like this:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

This code indicates that the `<App>` component will get rendered in the `root` element from your *index.html*.

So starting from the `<App>` component, you can build your component tree, because you never call `<Hord>`, it will never render, nor will the components rendered inside `<Hord>`.

Render `<Hord>` inside your `<App>` component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Hort from './Hort'
import Hord from './Hord'

function App(props) {
    const text1 = 'check1'
    return (
        <Hort test1={text1} />
        <Hord />
  );
}

export default App;
```

As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't `import` components that could cause infinite loops.

```js
import React from 'react'
// * removed imports

function Hort(props) {
    return (
       <div>
           <h1>Just {props.test1}</h1>
           <h2>Just {props.test2}</h2>
       </div>
    )
}

export default Hort;
```